# SAS- how to PROC EXPORT multiple PROC FREQ created by a macro?

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I have a macro which looks like this:

```
%macro mac_name (st, en=); 
  %do j=1 %to &en.;
  %let k=%eval(&j.+1);
      proc freq data=data_name;
        tables status&j. * status&k. / nocol norow nopercent missing;
      run;
  %end;
%mend;
%mac_name (st=1, en=%sysfunc(week(%sysfunc(today()), u)));
```

The output produces multiple proc freq tables with the same title.
I need this output put into a excel spreadsheet. Ideally all proc freqs in one sheet, one above the other or separate sheets.

Is this possible?

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to use `ODS EXCEL`, if you have SAS 9.4.

```
ods excel file="yourfilename.xlsx";
proc freq data=sashelp.class;
  tables age;
run;

proc freq data=sashelp.class;
  tables sex;
run;
ods excel close;
```

You have options for whether they're all on one sheet or separate sheets.  You can use `ODS TAGSETS.EXCELXP` if you have an earlier version of SAS, though they're less "true excel" files.  You can also make CSV files or various other things with `ODS`.

In your case you'd put the opening `ODS EXCEL` line before the first *call* of the macro (doesn't have to precede the definition of the macro) and then the `ODS EXCEL CLOSE` line after the last call.

Comment: Worked perfectly